# How to make a Generic Type Cast function

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I want to make a generic function for doing some operations, like:

```
ConvertValue<T>(string value)
```

If `T` is `int` then the function will convert the value to `int` and return the result.

Similarly, if `T` is `boolean`, the function will convert the `value` to `boolean` and return it.

How to write this?

Comment: Have you seen the Convert class? No point in reinventing the wheel unless you need something special. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: BTW, that's a conversion not a cast.

Comment: Casting causes the explicit conversion operator to be called anyway.

Comment: May I suggest using [ValueString](https://github.com/safakgur/value-string)?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public static T ConvertValue<T>(string value)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
int val = ConvertValue<int>("42");
```

**Edit:**

You can even do this more generic and not rely on a `string` parameter provided the type `U` implements `IConvertible` - this means you have to specify two type parameters though:

```
public static T ConvertValue<T,U>(U value) where U : IConvertible
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

I considered catching the `InvalidCastException` exception that might be raised by `Convert.ChangeType()` - but what would you return in this case? `default(T)`?  It seems more appropriate having the caller deal with the exception.

Comment: Nicely done. Just a usage note, though: don't forget to implement exception handling for unsupported conversions.

Comment: @Evan: see my update - I think the caller should handle this exception since there is no good way to handle it within the conversion method - returning `default(T)` sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: I agree. There is no clean way to handle it within the helper method. If I were using this, I would surround the call with a `try-catch` block.

Comment: Not to forget that this wont handle null for value types, say for eg, `ConvertValue<int>(null)` explodes unlike `Convert.ToInt32(null)` which will return 0. This can be desirable, but is a slight difference in behaviour nevertheless, keep in mind. Another subtle difference is that, constraining to `IConvertible` is not strictly needed since `Convert.ChangeType(new object(), typeof(object))` returns the object itself even though `System.Object` is not `IConvertible`, ie, if the input and output types are the same, then `IConvertible`-ity doesn't matter.

Comment: If the cast fails, FormatException is thrown, not InvalidCastException. Otherwise great answer.

Comment: I agree with @BrokenGlass in that `ConvertValue` should _not_ Handle Exceptions.  BUT, I believe that you could and should _also_ have the a `TryConvertValue` (a la `Int.TryParse`) that _does_ Handle Exceptions and return `default(T)`.

Comment: It is good to mention that using this approach is about 30 times costly compared to a pure cast, according to my tests. On my machine, for 10^8 casts, it takes 00:00:05.6143565 compared to 00:00:00.1924772

Comment: Is it still the only solution?

Answer (score 10):

While probably not as clean looking as the `IConvertible` approach, you could always use the straightforward checking `typeof(T)` to return a `T`:

```
public static T ReturnType<T>(string stringValue)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        return (T)(object)1;
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(FooBar))
        return (T)(object)new FooBar(stringValue);
    else
        return default(T);
}

public class FooBar
{
    public FooBar(string something)
    {}
}
```

Comment: This technique is useful when you want specialized logic for certain types

Answer (score -2):

ConvertValue( System.Object o ), then you can branch out by o.GetType() result and up-cast o to the types to work with the value.

Comment: OP specifically asked for something using generics