# Casting HtmlString to T

Tags: c#, web

I have inherited code which I have had to decompile,

From the code I am getting one problem which I can not solve, Casting a object to HtmlString to T

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(IHtmlString))
{
  return (T)(new HtmlString(value.ToString()));
}
```

The errors on build as a invalid cast expression, I have tried to use Convert.ChangeType but that also doesn't work.

```
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(new HtmlString(value.ToString()), typeof(T));
```

Starting to run out of idea's, anyone have any solution?

Comment: Have to tried the `where U : IConvertible` constraint: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6884667/284240

Comment: can you post complete method?

Comment: What about `return (T)(object)(new HtmlString(value.ToString()));`?  But really checking the type of `T` and casting kinda defeats the whole purpose of using generics in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around this by casting to `object` first.

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(IHtmlString))
{
  return (T)(object)(new HtmlString(value.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(IHtmlString))
{
   dynamic result = new HtmlString(value.ToString());
   return (T)result;
}
```