# How do I create a C# generic method that takes in one generic type and returns another generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, methods

How do I create a C# generic method that takes in one generic type and returns another generic type? How do i get the actual Type of T so that i can return my new type as that generic T type.

Basically, I want to achieve something like this sample code where the `if`/`else` logic converts between types. If there's a better way to do the same thing like with using Func please let me know. Any help would be appreciated. thank you.

**EDIT:**
OK this is almost exactly what I want to do. (Just the types are different) I don't think "Convert.ChangeType" would work because I am using custom types.

```
public interface ICustomType{}    
public struct TypeA : ICustomType {}
public struct TypeB : ICustomType {}
public struct TypeC : ICustomType {}

public static T Convert<T>(ICustomType input) where T : ICustomType
{
    var output = default(T);

    if (output is TypeA)
    {
        if (input is TypeA)
        {
            output = input;
        }
        else if (input is TypeB)
        {                
            output = CustomTypeB_ToTypeA_Converter(input);
        }
        else if (input is TypeC)
        {
            output = CustomTypeC_ToTypeA_Converter(input);
        }
    }
    else if (output is TypeB)
    {
        if (input is TypeA)
        {
            output = CustomTypeA_ToTypeB_Converter(input);
        }
        else if (input is TypeB)
        {                
            output = input;
        }
        else if (input is TypeC)
        {
            output = CustomTypeC_ToTypeB_Converter(input);
        }
    }
    else if (output is TypeC)
    {
       // same pattern as above
    }
    return output;
}
```

**possible use case:**

```
TypeA a = 45;
TypeB result = Convert<TypeB>(a);
```

Comment: can you show example of what you are trying to do?... also generic return types cannot be inferred by compiler. if generic type is only used for return you have to specify it when calling the method.

Comment: You might be interested in [Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: There are still plenty of Convert methods in .Net, just use `Convert.`

Comment: possible duplicate [generic type cast function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884653/how-to-make-a-generic-type-cast-function)

Comment: I would provide more background on what's your actual goal. I'm not sure if generics fit well in your case....

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I updated my code sample to reflect the exact thing i am trying to do.

Comment: @MatiasFidemraizer is my edit clearer? its exactly what i am working on but the type names are different

Comment: @MongZhu inheritance would not work because i just want this method to be in my util class that i can call from from TypeA, TypeB or TypeC when i want to explicitly convert between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a break I came back and was able to solve my problem. It turns out all i had to do was pass my type back as the constraint interface and then cast it to the generic T before i return it. And that's it, everything worked. Thanks all for the help.

```
public interface ICustomType{}    
public struct TypeA : ICustomType {}
public struct TypeB : ICustomType {}
public struct TypeC : ICustomType {}

public static T Convert<T>(ICustomType input) where T : ICustomType
{
    var output = default(T);

    if (output is TypeA)
    {
        if (input is TypeA)
        {
            output = (T)input;
        }
        else if (input is TypeB)
        {  
            // first assign my type to ICustomType interface
            ICustomType typeA =  CustomTypeB_ToTypeA_Converter(input);
            // then cast that interface to the generic T before you return it             
            output = (T)typeA;
        }
        else if (input is TypeC)
        {  
            // first assign my type to ICustomType interface
            ICustomType typeC =  CustomTypeC_ToTypeA_Converter(input);
            // then cast that interface to the generic T before you return it             
            output = (T)typeC;
        }
    }
    else if (output is TypeB)
    {
        // same pattern as above
    }
    else if (output is TypeC)
    {
       // same pattern as above
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var str = "1.0";

    decimal result = Convert(str, ConvertToDecimal);
}

public static decimal ConvertToDecimal(string str)
{
    return decimal.Parse(str);
}

public static TOut Convert<TIn, TOut>(TIn item, Func<TIn, TOut> f)
{
    return f(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't know anything about the types the best thing you could do is basically to use the ChangeType method as suggested by Rob and Rabban:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "1";
        double d = Convert<string, double>(s);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }

    public static TOut Convert<TIn, TOut>(TIn text)
    {
        return (TOut)System.Convert.ChangeType(text, typeof(TOut));
    }
}
```

Note that this will throw an exception at runtime if you try to use the method with incompatible values and types though:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "T";
        //THIS WILL THROW A FORMATEXCEPTION
        double d = Convert<string, double>(s);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
```

So using generics like this is probably not the best way to solve whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: ChangeType will not work cause I am using custom types. I updated my code sample to reflect the actual code i am working on.

Comment: The main purpose of generics is to provide compile-time type safety...You have something like a factory method that tries to create an instance of an ICustomType based on another one that is passed in to the method. Then it is the factory method itself that should be responsible for knowing how to and create the new instance based on your specific logic. You cannot really make this conversion logic "generic".

Comment: thanks for observation, do you have any suggestion on an alternate way i could go about doing this? I am at a mental block right now. thanks

Comment: Like I said, implement your Convert method to perform the conversion based on your logic. Create an instance of the type T in the method and set its properties to the appropriate values based on the input type. All properties that are not part of common ICustomType interface will have to be set using reflection. Only you can be supposed to know how to create an instance of TypeA given an instance of TypeB. The compiler certainly doesn't.